# Stream builder to populate data from a list of food items in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new to flutter
i have a list of food items which hold dishes to show in cart.

```
var foodList = <Food>[];
```

and Food class

```
class Food {
 String dishID;
 String restID;
 String dishName;
 String dishPrice;

Food({
 required this.dishID,
 required this.restID,
 required this.dishName,
 required this.dishPrice});
}
```

i want to use this list as a stream for stream builder, but i cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: Why a stream builder? It's not  a stream, is it? For lists just use a `ListView`

Comment: `Stream.fromIterable` maybe? but actually I would agree with the comment above: why `StreamBuilder`?

Comment: previously i used future builder, reason to use Streambuilder was to update the list if i delete the dish from the list.

Comment: for now, when i delete the dish it still shows whereas it is deleted from the list